# What was pharaoh's and his people's change of heart of sending away the Jewish people from Egypt

Tags: yetziat-mitzrayim, beshalach

[here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53200/why-did-pharaohs-officers-wait-for-three-whole-days-before-returning-to-inform) are the pesukim. It says pharaoh and his servants  had a change of heart. Rashi says that the end of the posuk only refers to pharaoh but not to his servants. Their change of heart was because they "lost" their valuables.

So my question is what exactly was their change of heart. They originally thought they were going for three days and this never changed. 
And also why did they have to fool pharaoh and not tell him straight out the truth that they were going for good.

Comment: Considering this question is downvoted it is therefore not worth answering

Answer (score 1):

Lets look at this "change" they had the following way:

You have a cleaner that always cleans for you and you love her work, in fact she is amazing at it!
One day she gets up and asks you is she can leave for three days and you say yes. So now you will have to clean yourself for the next three days. Now you tell yourself "Okay I can do this for 3 days its not that bad..." so you tell her its okay. Now you start thinking about it and you realize how bad of an idea it was and you decide that her leaving is actually a bad idea and now you want her back.

Same with the Egyptians that realized they can't live with out the Jews and so they need them!

If we would of said that we are leaving forever they would of thought about it and then said no but since we said three days they thought they can live with it.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I shall give my own original answer when the question is appreciated